# How to group rows while filtering out values per each group?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Imagine you have the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE namechanges (
  id text,
  new_name text,
  change_date timestamp
);

INSERT INTO namechanges VALUES
  ('x', 'alice', '2020-03-01'),
  ('y', 'Bob T.', '2020-03-03'),
  ('x', 'Alice', '2020-03-05'),
  ('z', 'charlie', '2020-03-07'),
  ('x', 'Alice C.', '2020-03-09'),
  ('z', 'Charlie Z.', '2020-03-11')
```

How would look like a query that would retrieve just the current name for each id and return the following?

```
| id  | max        |
| --- | ---------- |
| z   | Charlie Z. |
| y   | Bob T.     |
| x   | Alice C.   |
```

Here's the example above on DB Fiddle if you want to play with it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ugNcXhRyb44KTpqjFXmKDW/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better way of doing what you want to do is to use the [`ROW_NUMBER() Analytic function`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) as follows (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e11601f62776966bf54233dd7cabda0)). It avoids the "workaround" of concatenating strings and these functions are great - see below.

```
SELECT rn, id, new_name, change_date 
FROM  
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id  ORDER BY id, change_date DESC) as rn,
    id, new_name, change_date
  FROM namechanges
  ORDER  BY id, change_date DESC
) AS tab
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id, change_date;
```

Result:

```
rn  id  new_name    change_date
1   x   Alice C.    2020-03-09 00:00:00
1   y   Bob T.      2020-03-03 00:00:00
1   z   Charlie Z.  2020-03-11 00:00:00
```

Analytic (aka Window) [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) are very powerful and will reward, a gazillion fold, time spent learning them! I've left the steps in the logic that I followed in the fiddle, so that (plus the tutorial link above) should give you a good start.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres this can be solved using [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select distinct on (id) *
from namechanges
order by id, change_date desc;
```

This is typically faster than using aggregation or Window functions.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c4324a07f34efe9a678026afd8b54e0)

Comment: True - [your solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8439415b2651417b0901e91a4e5fc832) - `Planning Time: 0.155 ms Execution Time: 0.118 ms` and [mine]( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8439415b2651417b0901e91a4e5fc832) - `Planning Time: 0.222 ms Execution Time: 0.281 ms` - yours is ~ > 50% better! Nice one (+1) **but**, my solution is standards compliant! :-)

Comment: @Vérace: yes, absolutely. It's also more versatile as it can easily be extended to "the two most recent changes" or similar variatioins.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that seems to work for the case above on PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT id, max((change_date || '-' || new_name))
FROM namechanges
GROUP BY id;
```

That will return the last name, although prefixed with the date. I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it and how performant it is.